# Why liquibase:updateDatabase ant task does not support labels?

Tags: liquibase

As I see in version 3.3 labels feature were provided. I would really love to use them but it's currenty impossible because lack of handling labels in ant database tasks. Is it handled in some other way ?? Additionally i would like to know how could I add an issue to liquibase jira.

Comment: I don't use ant but I don't understand why it should not be possible to use labels (or contexts) with ant? Ant should just be a way to call/start liquibase. It should still read your changelog.xml files and that's were you define your labels... Maybe I just don't understand your question...

Comment: Also, please read this page for more information on writing good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Jens For Liquibase exists database ant tasks like liquibase:updateDatabase. This task handles usage of context by specifying context attribute. The same is not possible for labels, so you cannot run changesets via ant task with labels feature.

Comment: @SteveDonie Ok, but could you point me what is wrong with this question ? Only one thing what i see is that in fact this are two questions inside one. Anything else ?

Comment: It might be just missing in the documentation. Did you try to use `labels` just like `contexts`?

Comment: @Artur, a good question has 3 things:
1. This is what I did (exact steps, commands given, relevant files involved, perhaps the OS you are using, versions of different things, etc.)
2. This is what I expected to happen (output from command, expected state of system afterwards, etc.)
3. This is what actually happened (output, error logs, etc.)

You did not have any of those 3 things. I was able to infer that you were using ant from the post title, but your build.xml was not included, nor was the command line you gave. I can guess at expected behavior, but you did not share the actual behavior.

Comment: @Jens You are right, you can look at my answer to SteveDonie comment

Comment: @SteveDonie Ok, thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

To add something to the Liquibase Jira, you just need to sign up for an account here:

https://liquibase.jira.com/login?

After your account is created, you will be able to create new issues.

As far as the Ant tasks go, it appears that you should be able to use labels and contexts in the Ant tasks. If you could include an Ant build file that shows any problems you are having along with the command you are using and the output, we can help address those issues.

Comment: ok I see. I mean that liquibase ant tasks like `liquibase:updateDatabase` don't have an attribute to handle labels. For the task mentioned above exists attribute for handling contexts. But there is no any attribute to handle labels. So I'm not able to run changesets with usage of labels via ant task. You can check it in liquibase documentaion here [link](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/ant/updatedatabase_ant_task.html)

Comment: I am going to second what Jens said above. I think the documentation is lacking. Liquibase is pretty much a one-man project, so sometimes the docs lag behind the actual code.

Comment: i've checked this again today. I've made typo because i specified `label` instead of `labels` attibute. And now it works. And yes, the documentation is lacking

Comment: @SteveDonie: Sorry to miss-use this a little but do you know if there are more people that have access to the liquibase doc so it can be updated by others? (we don't have to discuss this here in deep. It came to my mind just now.)

Comment: The liquibase docs are in github. Anyone can edit them and submit pull requests.